# Ring of Gaussian integers modulo p=4n+3

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

How can I prove that there are no Zero divisors in the Ring of Gaussian integers modulo p=4n+3, where p is prime, n is integer?

Thank you.

Comment: What is "the ring of Gaussian integers modulo a prime $\;p=3\pmod 4\;$" ?

Comment: @DonAntonio It isn't "Gaussian (integers modulo $p$)", it's "(Gaussian integers) modulo $p$"

Comment: The ring of complex numbers $x=a+bi$, where a and b are both integers, modulo p (p is prime number which can be witten as 4n+3, where n is integer).

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I see...hehe. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this follow from the fact that a commutative unitary ring is a field whenever we take the quotient modulo a maximal ideal?

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes, _if_ we knew that that ideal was maximal. The ideals generated by (rational) primes $p=1\mod 4$ are _not_ maximal... So, presumably, this exercise is to figure out the distinction.

Comment: @paulgarrett Well, I've no idea what the OP knows or not. This is perhaps the main reason they are required to add some self work. Proving that only primes $\;=1\pmod4\;$ are sums of squares is more or less elementary...and from that one can figure out the difference between those primes...perhaps the OP will throw some light on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to prove that the ideal $(p)$ of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is prime, which amounts to saying that $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. This is generally not the same as saying that $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$: for instance, $2$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, but it is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, as $2=(1+i)(1-i)$, but $2$ divides neither $1+i$ nor $1-i$.

However, prime and irreducible elements are the same in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, because it is a Euclidean domain, so we may as well prove that $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Suppose $p=xy$, for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then we have also $p=\bar{x}\bar{y}$ (using complex conjugation), so by multiplying term by term,
$$
p^2=|x|^2|y|^2
$$
This is now a relation in the integers and we have three possibilities:

1. $|x|^2=p^2$, $|y|^2=1$;
2. $|x|^2=p$, $|y|^2=p$;
3. $|x|^2=1$, $|y|^2=p^2$.

In cases 1 and 3, we conclude that one of the factors is invertible (why?). If we can exclude case 2, we have proved that $p$ is indeed irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Write $x=a+bi$, so $|x|^2=a^2+b^2$.

Can you now prove that $p=a^2+b^2$ is impossible, when $a$ and $b$ are integers?

> Here you have to use the fact that $p=4n+3$. Further hint: reduce modulo $4$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Can you please explain me some steps? 1) P is prime iff there are no zero divisors? Is it because in that case there can't be found x,y: $x*y = p = 0 (mod p)$? 2) 1 is invertible in Z[i] so in cases 1 and 3 one of the factors in invertible - but why does it mean that these cases are impossible? 3) Yeah, second case is clear, thanks.

Comment: @SilverLight (1) The ideal $P$ of the commutative ring $R$ is prime if and only if there are no zero divisors in $R/P$. (2) $|x|^2=1$ implies $x=1$ or $x=-1$ or $x=i$ or $x=-i$ (prove it).